# Visual force page inside napili community is coming up as screenshot

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, napili

I have a Visual force page which picks up a file from one's system and stores the chosen file as document in salesforce.Now I want to use it inside my napili community.

First I tried using iframe inside my custom component however when this component renders inside community the vf page displayed is just a screenshot of the button(not able to click button/choose file)

```
<aura:component>
<iframe src="https://mydomain..salesforce.com/apex/visualforcepagename"/>
</aura:component>
```

,then I tried adding the visual force page from community builder(drag and drop) and this time also the community page on preview had the Vf page with button screenshot.

So could anybody help me in finding out where exactly i would be making mistake.

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript error in console?

Comment: VFDevModeWithViewstate.js:13 Failed to load '' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.   2)   
 document.getElementsByClassName @ VFDevModeWithViewstate.js:13
sessionserver204.html:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.
3)   login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: when i add the same frame inside any visual force page and preview ,it works fine even after getting errors in console.       === console errors===   1)  sessionserver204.html:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.

2)    login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
sessionserver204.html:1 Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'reflected-xss'.

3)    login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: first 2 errors are different if we compare both logs